# Select other data in another table using eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have cases, cases_judges, judges and witness tables.
A case can have many judges and witness
I want to be able to select all the judges and witness associated to a case
I don't know how to create a relationship between case and judges because their is no direct link between judges and case. Cases_judges is the only intermediary between case and judge. I also tried using Hasmanythrough relationship but without success

**Cases model**

```
    public function case_judges(){
      return $this->hasMany(Cases_judges::class,'case_id','id');
    }
    public function witness(){
      return $this->hasMany(Witness::class,'case_id','id');
    }
   public function judges(){
      return $this->hasManyThrough(Judges::class, Case_judge::class,'judge_id','id');
   }
```

**Judges model**

```
public function judges(){
  return $this->hasMany(Case_judge::class,'case_id','id');
}
```

**Cases_judge model**

```
public function case(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Cases::class);
}
```

**Cases Controller**
My case controller is something like this
public function index()
{

```
     return Cases::with('case_judge','witness')->get();
   
}
```

This fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/217dcb/2/0)shows how I would have done it using raw query but I want to do it the eloquent way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To arrive at the solution, first we have to uncover what *really* is the relationship between your `Case` and `Judge` models.

[image]

The simplified diagram highlights the connection between your `Case` and `Judge` models via an intermediate `CaseJudge` model. Indeed, a `Case` really can have multiple `Judge`s. However, we must not miss out the fact that a `Judge` can handle multiple `Case`s.

From this, we can conclude that `Case` and `Judge` models have a many-to-many relationship.

To establish a many-to-many relationship between models in Laravel, you must use [`belongsToMany`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship method, as opposed to `hasManyThrough` which only applies to one-to-many relationship.

```php
class Cases extends Model {
  ...

  public function judges() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Judges::class, 'case_judges', 'case_id', 'judge_id');
  }
}
```

Here, `belongsToMany` has four arguments:

1. Model that has the many-to-many relationship with our `Cases` model.
2. Intermediate table connecting tables `cases` and `judges`.
3. Foregin key on intermediate table that connects to table `cases`.
4. Foregin key on intermediate table that connects to table `judges`.

When all is set and done, running:

```php
return Cases::with(['judges', 'witness'])->get();
```

will now return what you want — a collection of cases, along with witnesses and judges associated to their respective cases.

<sub>As a side note: you might want to follow Laravel's [conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) on naming things, to avoid running into weird default Eloquent behaviors as consequence, and enjoy any conveniences it brings when you conform to these conventions.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I think `cases` and `judges` are 'Many to Many' relationship with intermediate table `cases_judges`.

You can follow this document to setup this : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many